# Missing folders via MTP connection

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, usb, windows, mtp

When connecting an Android device (KitKat) to a Windows box via USB, and specifying the use of MTP, recent folder additions are often not visible on the Windows end.

Is this because the Android Media Scanner needs more time to run in order to find all those new folders?  Or is there a different explanation?

Comment: Maybe you can try to force [Media Scan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.house.noranuko.mediarescanner) and then see if those recent files appear..